# Return textbox value after press cancel button

Tags: php, html, textbox

I have code like this:

```
<?php
    $name = "edward";
    $country = "Indonesia";
?>

<form id="bio">
    <input type="text" id="name" value="<?= $name ?>">
    <input type="text" id="country" value="<?= $country?>">
</form>

<button class="clear">Cancel</button>
```

So when first load, the textboxes are filled according the variable I defined before. Then I change / type something in both textbox name or country. How to make the text box value value back as before (textbox name filled by edward, and country is filled by Indonesia - both filled by it's default value) when I press cancel button ? Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `HTML5` use

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="<?= $name ?>">
<input type="text" id="country" placeholder="<?= $country?>">
<button class="clear" type="reset">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Or use JavaScript

Comment: `placeholder="<?= $name ?>"`? shouldn't be `value="<?= $name ?>"`

Comment: by default value='' even if you don't mention it

Comment: it is not compulsory to write `value=''` in `input`

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `<input type="reset" />` instead of button?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable both are correct (html5)

Comment: @reenleedr i just never heard of buttons type attribute but i guess you're right.

Comment: if you trust [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) you can read there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the button's onclick to set the values back to normal:

```
<button class="clear" onclick="document.getElementById('name').value='<?=$name?>';document.getElementById('country').value='<?=$county?>';">Cancel</button>
```